# Azure Service Bus backplane for Signalr core

Tags: signalr, signalr-backplane, asp.net-core-signalr

is Azure Service Bus backplane available for signalr core.

which backplane is available for a signalr core app that is hosted on Azure cloud.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has no plans to do a service bus backplane this release. it is recommended that you use redis as it's more suited for volatile messaging.